# Why is corestoraged preventing sleep in macOS 10.12.3?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

I've noticed consistently that a day or so after reboot, my Mac will refuse to go to sleep. Activity Monitor shows that the process `corestoraged` is preventing sleep. If I reboot, it will no longer be listed as a process preventing sleep -- until it starts doing so again.

Does anyone understand why this is happening? Is this a bug in 10.12.3?

Answer (score 1):

1) If FileVault is encrypting your disk you will see `corestoraged` as a blocking process.

2) If Time Machine is encrypting an external drive with backup `corestoraged` will be also blocking sleep (even if the backup disk is unmounted and not connected to the Mac!!!).

```
➜  ~ pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
standbydelay         10800
standby              1
womp                 1
halfdim              1
hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
powernap             1
gpuswitch            2
networkoversleep     0
disksleep            10
sleep                10 (sleep prevented by corestoraged)
autopoweroffdelay    28800
hibernatemode        3
autopoweroff         1
ttyskeepawake        1
displaysleep         10
acwake               0
lidwake              1
```

In my case, it was the Time Machine. After it finished encryption of the backup disk (took a week or so) `corestoraged` is not longer causing a sleep issues.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't initially encrypting either my internal or external storage, but after running Disk Utility, corestorage doesn't seem to be preventing sleep.